# Is this sentence grammatically correct? Adverb clause

Tags: adverbs, clauses, modifiers

When I got back my test recently, I oddly found that my English teacher thinks that there is an error in the usage of adverbial clauses in

> "It seems that moving the body while learning, which forces the learner to concentrate, improves memory."

He claimed that *"which"* must come directly after the word it modifies, but I am still not convinced. Could someone kindly point out whether the sentence is grammatically correct or not. Please elaborate.

Comment: Isn't "moving the body while learning" the thing modified?

Comment: Where, exactly, did the teacher think 'which' should be ? If not, as commented above, directly after the thing modified.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong in this instance: it's OK. In defining relative clauses the relative word does normally occur straight after its antecedent noun. But "which forces the learner to concentrate" is a non-defining relative clause, and such relatives are not modifiers but supplements that don't combine with a noun to form a larger noun phrase, but are non-constituents, being either an interpolation (as in your ex) or an appendage. Rather than being modifiers, they have a semantic anchor that they refer to: in your example, the anchor is the clause "moving the body while learning".

Comment: What does the *which* stand for?

Comment: Further, even in defining relative clauses, it's not the relative word that is a modifier, but the whole relative clause. The relative word itself functions as some constituent within the relative clause, such as subject, object etc.

Comment: In the OP's example, "which" is the subject of the relative clause. It has the clause "moving the body while learning" as its antecedent.

Comment: @Lawrence That is what I tried to tell him.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which clauses with phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274438/which-clauses-with-phrases). See @Greg Lee's answer. Ambiguity should be avoided, but '**while** learning' here makes 'learning' unavailable as a substantive 'which forces the learner to concentrate' is post-modifying.

Comment: Maybe the teacher thought that the sentence should be *"It seems that moving the body while learning forces the learner to concentrate, which improves memory."*

Comment: Non-defining relatives are not modifiers but supplements. That is crystal clear from the fact that they don't combine with a head noun to form a larger NP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Dangling Participles"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148766/dangling-participles)

Answer (score 1):

When considering this answer, please note that just because something is a grammatical English sentence, that doesn't mean it counts as a correct answer to a question on an exam. It all depends on what the question actually asked and on any 'ground rules' that the teacher may have set up.

Having said all that, there is nothing wrong with your sentence **as an English sentence**. It is fine both as far as formal grammar and as far as rules of good writing. As far as the latter, I'm not saying that the sentence couldn't be improved. However, I **am** saying that any modification in order to improve it would be a matter of personal preference and style, not of grammar.

**If** your teacher is really saying that, **as a matter of grammar**, *which* must immediately follow the **word** it refers to, **then** your teacher is indeed mistaken, in several respects. First of all, the antecedent of *which* need not be a single word at all; it may be a whole noun phrase (NP) or a whole nonfinite clause (the latter, in fact, is the case in your sentence). Second, the reason why people sometimes say such things is to help novices avoid writing confusing and ambiguous sentences. The actual rule (of good writing) is that it should be clear to the reader what it is that *which* refers to. If it is clear, then there is no problem.

**Discussion**

Here is a relevant passage from [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (p. 1035). Note that, in CGEL's terminology, your relative clause (*which forces the learner to concentrate*) is a **supplementary relative clause**:

> The supplementary relative is also distinguished from the integrated relative in that  it permits a much wider range of antecedents, as is evident from such examples as:
>
> [3]  i  *Pat is **afraid of snakes**, which I'm sure Kim is too.*                     [AdjP] 
>         ii  ***Pat is afraid of snakes***, which doesn't surprise me at all.       [clause]
>
> The antecedents for *which* here are an AdjP [adjective phrase) in [i] and a whole clause in [ii], the relative clauses being interpreted as "I'm sure Kim is **afraid of snakes** too" and "That **Pat is afraid of snakes** doesn't surprise me at all". The antecedent can indeed be a piece of text syntactically unconnected to the relative, as when a lecturer finishes one topic and then moves on to the next with the supplementary relative *Which brings me to my next point*.

Here are more examples from published literature:

> *So far no such reaction has been found, **which** may be due simply to...* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=1TrDAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT62&dq=%22found%2C%20which%22&pg=PT62#v=onepage&q=%22found,%20which%22&f=false)
>   (Speaking of circumcision:) *In general both Greeks and Romans found the custom repulsive and ridiculous, **which** led to tensions especially with Jews.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=TkW_BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT423&dq=%22ridiculous%2C%20which%22&pg=PT423#v=onepage&q=%22ridiculous,%20which%22&f=false)
>   *Change takes a long time to sink in here, **which** is also why, whenever I identified myself as the writer come to write about the village and La Récréation, they looked momentarily puzzled.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=z7g4w10u0C8C&lpg=PA17&dq=%22here%2C%20which%22&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q=%22here,%20which%22&f=false)
>   *Illumined and elevated by his grace and favor, they adored what they saw in him, **which** they did not previously see because of their blindness and lowliness.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=1vfdkDs8Cv4C&lpg=PT380&dq=%22which%20they%20did%22&pg=PT380#v=onepage&q=%22%20what%20they%20saw%20in%20him,%20which%20they%20did%20not%20previously%20see%22&f=false)
>   *Abigail also regularly wrote personal letters, **which** was her method of staying in touch with friends.* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=9o6h8mliOuoC&lpg=PA8&dq=%22which%20was%20her%22&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q=%22which%20was%20her%22&f=false); note that it is *which was* and not *which were*. Therefore, *which* doesn't refer to *letters*, which would require the plural *were*, but to 'regularly writing personal letters', which takes singular agreement.)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply, and I apologize for not clearing up what the question was: It was "Combine each of the following pairs of sentences into a complex sentence using an adjective or an adverb clause. 1. It seems that moving the body while learning improves memory. Movement forces the learner to concentrate." I assume that, in this case, I should not have a mark deducted.

Comment: Wish me luck trying to convince him to give me my mark back.

Comment: @Omarkamal Unfortunately, there is also a matter of any relevant 'ground rules', which may have been laid down previously in the course.  For example, the teacher may have said during the lectures that he will insist on *which* following the word it modifies.  And he may have good reasons for insisting on that in this particular class, reasons informed by his teaching experience. In that case, the only way he could be 'wrong' is if the question is impossible to answer given the rules. So it would be helpful if you could reproduce the exact wording of the question, in its totality.

Comment: Further, non-defining relatives are not modifiers.

Comment: @BillJ You're right; I've rephrased.

Comment: So, ground rules aside, is the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: @Omarkamal As I said in my replay, it is a perfectly fine sentence in English. So, yes, it is grammatically correct.